# JSON.parse returning [Object Object] instead of value

Tags: javascript, html, json

My API returning the JSON value like

```
[{"UserName":"xxx","Rolename":"yyy"}]
```

I need `Username` and `RoleName` value seperatly i tried JSON.parse but its returning [Object Object] Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-usefult-to-others-in-future. The parsing is working just fine; it's just that when you output the first element, you're just outputting the object, not one of its properties. The default `toString` on an object outputs `[object Object]` (if it's a plain object).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Show us the code that's producing the output you describe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider the following:

```js
    var str = '[{"UserName":"xxx","Rolename":"yyy"}]'; // your response in a string
    var parsed = JSON.parse(str); // an *array* that contains the user
    var user = parsed[0];         // a simple user
    console.log(user.UserName);   // you'll get xxx
    console.log(user.Rolename);   // you'll get yyy
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data is a string then you need to parse it with `JSON.parse()` otherwise you don't need to, you simply access it as is.

```js
// if data is not in string format
const data = [{"UserName":"xxx","Rolename":"yyy"}];

const username = data[0].UserName
const rolename = data[0].Rolename

console.log(username)
console.log(rolename)

// if data is in string format
const strData = JSON.parse('[{"UserName":"xxx","Rolename":"yyy"}]');

const Username = strData[0].UserName
const Rolename = strData[0].Rolename

console.log(Username)
console.log(Rolename)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an `array`. Then need to get `0th` element very first

This will work

```js
let unps =  JSON.parse('[{"UserName":"xxx","Rolename":"yyy"}]')[0]
console.log(unps.UserName, unps.Rolename);
```