# JSON parse with string literals with nested objects in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Problem with JSON.parse in nested json object string

I have a author object as:

```
var a = {"firstName":"abhi", "lastName":"pat"}
```

Am using the JSON parse with other data as:

```
JSON.parse(`{"name": "u", "author": "${a}"}`)
```

I got the the output as:

```
{name: "u", author: "[object Object]"}
```

The expected output is:

```
{name: "u", author: {firstName: "abhi", lastName: "pat"}}
```

Can anyone suggest me the right way to parse it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON.parse returning \[Object Object\] instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737093/json-parse-returning-object-object-instead-of-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stringify `a`, not put it directly into the JSON.

```
JSON.parse(`{"name": "u", "author": ${JSON.stringify(a)}}`)
```

But you shouldn't contruct JSON directly as a string in the first place, you should use `JSON.stringify()` for the whole thing:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({name: "u", author: a}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use other methods for object assign:

```
var a = {"firstName":"abhi", "lastName":"pat"}
console.log({"name": "u", "author": Object.assign({}, a)});
```

No need `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` methods.